# Getting a 404 when trying to redirect queries to symbolic directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Following is my .htaccess file. I'm trying to redirect ?page query requests to /page/, and make /page/ requests secretly load index.php?page in the background.

When I try loading http://url.url/page/id I get a 404 error. I've tested mod_rewrite on my server, and it works, so I'm certain the issue is with my code. The page names can consist of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ and -

Can anyone please provide an example of how to fix this?

```
RewriteEngine On
#Prevents rewriting for directories that exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
#Prevents rewriting for files that exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#Secretly loads index.php?page=* in the background for /page/* requests
RewriteCond ^page/(.*)$
RewriteRule ./index.php?page=$1
#Redirects all ?page=* requests to /page/*
RewriteCond ./index.php?page=(.*)$
RewriteRule /page/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond ./?page=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule /page/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code. Replace all of it by this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to redirect only http://domain.extension/index.php?query redirects to domain.extension/query - it works! But I need http://domain.extension/?page=* and index.php?page=* to forward to /page/*, and for /page/* to load ?page=* in the background.